# Why isn't my HTTP proxy connecting to an HTTPS website?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, httpx

I am trying to understand why a proxy is not connecting to the website, but displays my IP instead

```
import httpx
import asyncio

proxies = {"http": "http://34.91.135.38:80"}
async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(proxies=proxies) as client:
        s = await client.get('https://api.ipify.org')
        print(s.text)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

When I try to do that, it will display my IP, not the IP I selected. I want to be able to use my proxy to connect to the website

Comment: I think the key in your `proxies` dictionary needs to match the scheme of the URL: `"https"`. I've ever used https, though, so this is just a guess.